# How to pass input array to a JavaScript function for testing it in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

What I'm trying is to check my functions whether they return correct values.
And I want to see the returned value in debug console. Simple example:

```
function example(params) {

let start = parseInt(params[0])
let end = parseInt(params[1])
let sum = start + end
console.log(sum)

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just call your `function` with `example(yourArray);`

```
function example(params) {

  let start = parseInt(params[0])
  let end = parseInt(params[1])
  let sum = start + end
  console.log(sum)
}
example(yourArray);
```